Joint normality of infinite series
Consider a sequence of random variables where these variables are mutually independent and all have standard normal distribution. Denote this sequence S. Closure of span(S) forms a Hilbert space. Is it true that any finite set of variables from this Hilbert space forms a normal vector?
EDIT (clarification): The big Hilbert space is standard: it is the space of all square-integrable random variables with the inner product <X,Y>=E[XY]. More precisely, it is the space of the equivalence classes where equivalent variables differ on sets of probability zero. The underlying probability space is rich enough to allow a sequence of normal iid random variables on it. Cl(span(S)) is the Hilbert subspace.

"Closure of span($S$)" presumes these sequences lie within some larger topological space, but you haven't specified what that topological space is. Also "Hilbert" requires that there is an inner product defined, which you also haven't done. You cannot state Names, and assume that defines everything.

Right. The Hilbert space is standard: it is the space of all square-integrable random variables with the inner product <X,Y>=E[XY]. More precisely, it is the space of the equivalence classes where equivalent variables differ on sets of probability zero. The underlying probability space is rich enough to allow a sequence of normal iid random variables on it. Cl(span(S)) is the Hilbert subspace.
